# DRBD Single Primary Ignore File Types

Tags: puppet, synchronization, drbd, corosync

Is it possible to have an exclusion list for file types (maybe even specific files) so that they wont try to sync with the secondary nodes? I have looked at the DRBD configuration file and cannot find anything about it. If not is there another master->slave syncing system that allows for exclusions?

**Why I ask:**
Trying to move from a single server to a cluster behind a load-balancer infrastructure. I want to keep the servers operational/config files in sync. There are log files that are written in the same directories as their corresponding operational/config files.

**Optimal Goal:**
When master server (primary) has relevant files updated, slave (secondary) server files are synced.

I know I can restructure the code but I would really like to avoid that.

**Possibly Relevant Information:**
AWS ec2 servers
AWS Load Balancer
AWS NFS (EFS) was tried but performance hit was too large.
Could not get Jenkins to accomplish the goal either.
Thinking about setting up a Git Repo for the master, cloning the repo on the slaves, and then adding triggers whenever commits are made. Is there no better solution? Have not fully looked at Puppet could that be an option? Maybe Corosync? If you can point me to good use documentation as well that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, DRBD is a block-level synchronization tools and, as such, it can not (nor it should) care about what files are stored on the mirrored block device.

For keeping config file in check between multiple servers, you can give a look at [csync2](https://github.com/LINBIT/csync2) (which is another product by the makers of DRBD) or [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd) (which only works for unidirectional transfers, ie: from a primary node to a slave one).

Finally, you can simply use a custom rsync-based script (which, again, will only work well for unidirection primary->secondary transfers).

Comment: Thats what I thought. Any suggestions on what tool will accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: Give a look at the updated answer.